# Can I create an email alert workflow that triggers when an attachment is added to a case?

Tags: workflow, email-alert

This question was asked a number of years ago and the answer was essentially NO (without Apex programming) - Is this still the case?  And if so, how complicated would this be to program?

Comment: No, even with process builder or flow you would not be able to accomplish this with point&click.